# Handling syntax errors without stopping script execution

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, browser, async-await, legacy

I'm trying to deal with an older browser which throws an exception when I use an async function.

Because it's a syntax error, the script breaks even when I place it inside try/catch blocks. For example, the following produces a syntax error in older browsers and the script stops executing:

```js
try {
  async function foo() {
    console.log("bar"); 
  }
} catch(e) {
  function foo() {
    console.log("bar"); 
  }
}
```

At present my only solution is to place the function inside eval() as a string like so:

```js
try {
  eval('async function foo() {console.log("bar");}');
} catch(e) {
  function foo() {
    console.log("bar"); 
  }
}
```

Are there any alternative ways of approaching this?

I'm aware there are security and performance issues using eval(). In this case the string is hardcoded and is processed on the frontend. Are there vulnerabilities I should be aware of when using eval() in this context?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `eval()` is only unsafe if you can't trust the source of the string being evaluated. If it's hard-coded like this, you're OK.

Comment: But why not use something like Babel to transpile the code to something that will work on the older browsers?